# Translate objects along curve instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a set of start positions and a set of end positions and I eventually want to connect the two by bezier curve. And then use this bezier curve as a path for a selection of objects. I can get a single curve to work like this:

[image]

But when I try to make multiple curves the nodes no longer work.
[image]

The curves get connected like I want it to (picture 3), but the "sample curve node" does not output a field of each curve fac position value, instead it outputs the same vector for each instance. This is probably intended, but I would still like to get a fac position value for each independent curve. So I can animate objects moving along their own paths.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input of `Sample Curve` is not a *Field*, which is why you always get only one position.

But in your concrete case you don't need any curves to reach the desired position.

You already have all three necessary values at hand:

- start points
- end points
- factor

Therefore you would only have to take the vector between the two points and scale it with your desired factor.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you don't use straight lines, but arbitrary curves (e.g. `Quadratic Bezier`), then you would have to approach the matter differently:

If you use the node `Trim Curve` instead of `Sample Curve`, you can determine the point in the same way with a factor and then, as soon as you reduce the curve to a point, you get exactly the position you are looking for.

[image]

Here is the Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Yes, while this works for straight lines I would eventually like to replace the "curve line" with a 4 point bezier. So simple vector math does not work for me.

Comment: @jstkiko Ah, I see, if you don't have straight lines, then of course this method won't work. An update will follow shortly.